# alternate location for .npm folder (to avoid NFS-mounted home)

Tags: node.js, npm, nfs

I have an NFS-mounted home folder and am trying to set up global packages via npm, for example:

```
sudo npm install -g jshint
```

This gives me an error because under sudo I can't create anything on the remote server (tried this outside of npm)

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open '/home/explunit/.npm/a02a2468-jshint.lock'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open '/home/explunit/.npm/a02a2468-jshint.lock']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/explunit/.npm/a02a2468-jshint.lock' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

I'm sure somebody will come along in 2 minutes and say "don't use sudo -- a real developer would understand how to set up node/npm without it!", but a) it's never been clear to me how this is designed to work, given that the [npm readme](https://npmjs.org/doc/README.html) suggests sudo, and b) in this case I really don't want anything tied to my specific user (it's a build server)

So I guess the real question is how to make npm ignore my home folder and use some other location for .npm?

Comment: You could replace the `.npm` in your home directory with a symbolic link to a non-nfs location which could be made writable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to change where the cache is with this.

```
npm config set cache /SOMEWHERE/ELSE
```

/SOMEWHERE/ELSE should be somewhere where the user running the command can write.

Comment: thanks, but it looks like this still doesn't solve it in the "sudo npm install -g some_package" scenario since sudo will not be looking at the user's local npm config

Comment: `sudo npm -g config get cache` still gives me `~/.npm`.  the cache is only there to minimize what you need to download again.  Did you try it and it did not help?

Comment: yes, tried your command followed by the one from my original question above and got the same error. HOWEVER, looks like there's a --global that can be put on the end of your command that will make it apply even to the sudo environment settings. A similar command is also needed to set the tmp elsewhere

Comment: Doesn't help for me, because this command itself is trying to create `~/.npmrc`, while writing to `~` is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: `npm_config_userconfig=/tmp npm ...` will use /tmp for the location of the .npmrc

Answer (score 0):

I also faced troubles executing npm on nfs mounts, the issue for me was, that the nfs mount wasn't mounted executable, which is usually fine for storage locations, because  it protects you from executing potentially dangerous code downloaded from elsewhere.

Nevertheless sometimes you need to execute scripts from a nfs mount anyway. I recommend using  a separate mountpoint which then is mounted executable.

This can be reached as follows:

- Check your mount options:

```
mount | grep nfs
```

which lists your nfs mounts, such as e.g.:

```
device mountpoint nfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,nolock,addr=...)
```

- Take a closer look at the options section. If the '***noexec***' option is listed, you won't be able to execute some code from there, no matter what file permission you set with chmod.

So inside 'etc/fstab', instead of e.g.

```
device mountpoint nfs rw,nolock,users
```

use

```
device mountpoint nfs rw,nolock,exec
```

(the 'exec' and the 'users' option can interfere with each other, refer to the 'mount' manpage for their correct order if needed together)